# How to reuse argument in macros?

Tags: macros

I have the code of the appendix macros:

```latex
\newcommand{\application}[1]{\refstepcounter{application}%
{
  \par\vspace{\the\baselineskip}\centering{\bfseries\scshape%
  Приложение \theapplication \par}%
  (обязательное) \par%
  #1 \par%
  \vspace{\the\baselineskip}\par}%
  \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\scshape Приложение \theapplication ⟨here have to be #1 again⟩}%
}
```

I want to reuse the command name (attribute) to add it in the table of contents.

Comment: You can use `#1` as often as you like.

Comment: But I can't use it again in `\addcontentsline`

Comment: Sorry... It was my fault, I use the command without argument...

Comment: Well, I just made a generic, correct statement. If you want a specific answer for your problem, please consider making your question more specific: provide us with a small but complete document that is compilable except for the macro. In particular, all other ingredients are to be defined in this document.

Comment: @antray: Why can't you use `#1` in the `\addcontentsline`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Be aware that right after tokenizing an explicit character-token—`{` and `}` under normal circumstances get tokenized as explicit character tokens of category code 1(begin group) respective 2(end group)—and right after tokenizing a control symbol token— control symbol tokens are control sequence tokens whose name consists of a single character whose category code is not 11(letter)—space-characters in the current line of .tex-input get tokenized as space tokens (character-tokens of category code 10(space) and character code 32). Space tokens in turn yield horizontal glue in (restricted) horizontal mode.

Also be aware that LaTeX does pre-process lines of .tex-input-files line by line.

In the pre-processing stage (La)TeX removes all space-characters at the right end of the line and then appends a character to the line whose code-point-number in (La)TeX's internal character encoding scheme (which either is ASCII with traditional TeX-engines or is unicode with modern TeX-engines) corresponds to the value of the integer-parameter `\endlinechar`.  Usually the value of the integer-parameter `\endlinechar` is 13 while 13 is the code-point-number of the return-character both in ASCII and in unicode.
Usually the category code of the return-character is 5(end of line).
In case the reading-apparatus of LaTeX is in state S(skipping blanks) at the time of tokenizing a character of category code 5(end of line), that character will not at all yield insertion of a token into the token-stream. In case the reading-apparatus of LaTeX is in state N(new line) at the time of tokenizing a character of category code 5(end of line), that character will yield insertion of the token `\par` into the token-stream (no matter what the current meaning of `\par` is). In case the reading-apparatus of LaTeX is in state M(middle of line) at the time of tokenizing a character of category code 5(end of line), that character will yield insertion of a space token into the token-stream. (A space token is an explicit character token of category code 10(space) and character code 32; 32 denotes the number of the coding-point of the space-character both in ASCII and in unicode which are the internal character-encoding-schemes possible with (La)TeX-engines.)

Therefore behind the opening curly brace in the second line of

```
\newcommand{\application}[1]{\refstepcounter{application}%
{
```

LaTeX will due to the `\endlinechar`-thingie have inserted a return-character.

At the time of tokenizing that return-character

- LaTeX will just have tokenized the opening curly brace as an explicit character token of category code 1(begin group) and therefore LaTeX's reading-apparatus will be in state M(middle of line) and
- the category code of that return-character will be 5(end of line).

Therefore the inserted return-character will be tokenized as a space-token.

The space-token in turn yields horizontal glue in horizontal mode.

As that horizontal glue will be at the end of a paragraph, it will be discarded, so it won't matter.

Nonetheless you can save (La)TeX some work by not letting that space-token come into being at all.

Probably your command also works out as follows:

```
\newcommand{\application}[1]{%
  \refstepcounter{application}%
  {% <-begin of horizontally-centering-group
    \par
    \vspace{\baselineskip}%
    \centering
    {% <-begin of bf/sc-group
      \bfseries\scshape
      Приложение~\theapplication
      \par
    }% <-end of bf/sc-group
    (обязательное)%
    \par
    #1%
    \par
    \vspace{\baselineskip}%
    \par
  }% <-end of horizontally-centering-group
  \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{%
    {\protect\scshape Приложение\protect~\theapplication\space#1}%
  }%
}%
```

But you might be better off using `\text..`-commands:

```
\newcommand{\application}[1]{%
  \refstepcounter{application}%
  {% <-begin of horizontally-centering-group
    \par
    \vspace{\baselineskip}%
    \centering
    \textsc{\textbf{Приложение~\theapplication}}%
    \par
    (обязательное)%
    \par
    #1%
    \par
    \vspace{\baselineskip}%
    \par
  }% <-end of horizontally-centering-group
  \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{%
    \textsc{Приложение\protect~\theapplication\space#1}%
  }%
}%
```

In any case you should mention in the documentation of your `\application`-command that `\application` should not be nested inside `\application`'s argument as in this case, e.g., `\addcontentsline`-entries will go wrong.

And probably you don't wish to use `\par` that often, triggering the insertion of (vertical) `\parskip`-glue and tokens due to the `everypar`-hook etc, but wish to use `\linebreak` in some places—so perhaps:

```
\newcommand{\application}[1]{%
  \ifhmode\strut\fi % <- make sure the line above has some depth
  \par % <- finish the paragraph LaTeX is about to produce
       %    and switch to vertical mode.
  \refstepcounter{application}%
  %---------------------------------------------------------
  % Probably at this place locally redefine \application
  % to yield an error-message about nesting of \application
  % inside \application's argument not being allowed.
  %---------------------------------------------------------
  \vspace{\baselineskip}%
  \vbox{%
    % Things inside \vbox will always end up on same page.
    \centering
    \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{%
      \textsc{Приложение\protect~\theapplication\space#1}%
    }%
    \textsc{\textbf{Приложение~\theapplication}}%
    \linebreak % \par ?
    (обязательное)%
    \linebreak % \par ?
    #1%
    \ifhmode\strut\fi
  }%
  \vspace{\baselineskip}%
  % LaTeX should still be in vertical mode.
  % \parindent-glue/\parskip-glue etc will be added when LaTeX in
  % subsequent input finds things that cause it to enter (non-
  % restricted) horizontal mode which is the mode where you don't
  % do linebreaking manually but where LaTeX will break text of a
  % paragraph into lines for you.
}%
```

Comment: You might also remove `\the` when not needed.

Comment: @egreg You mean `\vspace{\the\baselineskip}` -> `\vspace{\baselineskip}` ?  Done. ;-)